# ¿Montar página html en localhost y que se actualice sola con VS Code?

Tags: html5, vscode

Verán, estoy practicando en HTML con vscode pero resulta que me toca abrir el archivo y estar actualizando cada vez que quiera hacer los cambios. Yo tengo xampp intalado y no se si se pueda colocar ese html en el apache y que el navegador actualice el html automaticamente con cada guardado o cambio.
Es que tengo 2 pantallas y es que quiero usar una pantalla programar y la otra para ir viendo como va quedando sin tener que ir a la otra pantalla a estar presionando F5.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: yo utilizo live Server que hace lo que tu mencionas de actualizar los cambios cada vez que guardas, no se si se puede hacer eso con xampp pero podrias utilizar live server para desarrollar y luego pasarlos a xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo uso la extension Live Server, crea un boton en la parte inferior derecha de la ventana llamado "Go Live", le das click  y te crea un servidor que corre en el puerto 5500 que se actualiza automaticamente cada vez que guardes un cambio en el archivo y te abre automaticamente tu archivo HTML con tu navegador predeterminado, aqui te dejo el link para descargar la extension en la tienda de extensiones oficial de VS Code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que te posiciones sobre tu carpeta con CMD o la terminal que prefieras (Git bash sirve, la instalas y le das click derecho dentro de la carpeta e inicias "gitbash here") y utilizes `npm i serve` sin las comillas... se instala super simple y te ofrece carpetas en tu navegador para que puedas verlo en forma gráfica... solo entras en cualquier navegador a localhost con el puerto que te dice (por lo general es `localhost:3000`) y listo saludos